# url params were cleared in `$rootScope.Scope#$digest` cycle

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to do `2-way` binding of the url params and the FORM elements.

I put a breakpoint inside `$locationChangeSuccess` and found the url params were cleared in  `$rootScope.Scope#$digest` cycle

I guess to modify `$location.search` in $scope.watch function is the buggy point?

How could I fix it? Thanks

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
        debugger
        console.log('$locationChangeSuccess changed!', new Date());
    });
});
```

## testA controller

```
  $scope.updateDeparture = function(departure){
      $scope.departure_name = departure.name;
  }

  $scope.$watch("departure_name", function(newValue, oldValue) {
      $location.search("departure_name", newValue);
  });
```

Comment: Do you use ui-router?

Comment: yes, i did include the ui-router

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here depending on do you want page reload on param change:

1) with reload. You store your params in object, watch it and if it changes use $state.go({param1: value1, ...}) -- you should define all params in state config. And on init you take your params from $stateParams

2) without reload. In state config you specify reloadOnSearch: false and must have url like mystate?param1=value1. (will not work for i.e. mystate/value1) Then again on init you take params from $stateParams and watch that params to update url.

But in 2 you will also need to $locationChangeSuccess to support back and forward buttons, as well as user direct change of param in url.